# update Mavericks to El Capitan with standalone installer

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, osx-el-capitan

my mac version is Mavericks now.
i have "Install OS X El Capitan.app" file in my hard disc.
how can i update my mac to El Capitan with this file ??
just update. not clean install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just doing an update (not a clean install), all you have to do is double-click it.  That's it.

It works regardless of what OS version you're on now (i.e. you don't have to upgrade to Yosemite first).

If you wanted to do a clean install, then there would be extra steps.  But the package itself is designed as an update, not a clean install, so there's nothing special you need to do.